# How to obtain the key with which a semaphore resource was defined in php?

Tags: php, semaphore

In php there is a function `sem_get` which returns an id that can be used to access the System V semaphore with some `key`:

```
resource sem_get ( int $key [, int $max_acquire = 1 [, int $perm = 0666 [, int $auto_release = 1 ]]] )
```

Given a semaphore resource, can I find out what `key` (i.e. what integer value) has been used to create this resource? Is there a way to 'invert' the `sem_get` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to simply keep an dictionary / associative array mapping `id` from sem_get to the `key` used to create it.

This associative array can be local/exclusive to each PHP process that you are using semaphores in because each call to sem_get results in a different id - therefore these ids will be useless to the other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think so. As if you use twice `sem_get` you will get different results but still for same key.